# How to run Matlab from Java code

Tags: java, matlab, octave

I was wondering if someone could tell me what the best way to run Matlab code in Java would be. I have never used Matlab nor do I have Matlab installed on my computer. I have been given a Matlab file that has a function which performs certain computations and returns performance measures. The function in Matlab uses other functions of the Matlab control toolbox. I would like to be able to call this function from my Java code. Is something like that possible and how?

Thank you!

Comment: I made an edit to add the Octave tag to your question. Maybe Octave users will have other options for you -assuming that your file runs (or can be made to) in Octave

Comment: I hope that you understand that product A cannot be useable in product B without product A, where A and B have no relation other than in the most general sense.

Comment: Integrating Matlab and Java is nasty. The 'official' way is to use the MathWorks JBuilder, which wraps the Matlab code up in a Java interface along with a stripped down version of Matlab to run it. There tends to be significant start up overhead when running it. If possible, you could try using octave and look into com automation.

Comment: I was assuming that this "Matlab file" you mention is a `.m` Matlab M-file containing source code (as opposed to an executable created with Matlab Compiler, e.g.). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a .m file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit*: If you don't have Matlab on your own machine, you can try running the file in [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/index.html). Hopefully Octave's [Control Toolbox](http://octave.sourceforge.net/control/) has what you need and is compatible. Then there are [javaOctave](https://kenai.com/projects/javaoctave/pages/Home) and [joPAS](http://jopas.sourceforge.net) to connect Octave to Java. Or maybe you could ask to be given a copy of Matlab. :-)

I don't know about interacting with Octave, but one possibility for Matlab is to use the [matlabcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) Java API. You'll still need to be on a computer with a Matlab license (and licenses for all of the necessary toolboxes).

Another possibility might be the MathWorks' [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/). Most Matlab installs don't come with it, so it would cost extra. They say it works with "[most toolboxes](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/description2.html)." There is a free trial.

On OS X or Linux I'm wondering if it might even be possible to [pipe commands](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=java+command+line+pipe) in and out of the [command line version of Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html) (or Octave) from a Java program...

Comment: I have tried piping from Matlab to Java on Mac, it works. But good luck finding out how, I spent much longer than it was worth.  You would think things like this would be documented given it was a matlab command but no.

Answer (score -1):

A GREAT QUESTION!  Given the fact that Matlab/Simulink has Java source it is ridiculous that the integration is not tighter.

Has anyone ever seen Matlab's performance.. it's terrible.  The designers should have realized that people would want to use it from other languages and at least have made a real manual on it rather than some half-a matlabcontrol written by third-party.

Piping is nice but has its own set of problems, mainly with portability. IMO you should not bother with anything other than rolling your own TCP/IP or UDP client/server in Matlab.  That is not difficult. The protocol you choose on top of it may be, but that is up to you.

I have tried the alternatives.

But honestly if your a beginner just learn matlab it is not harder than java and will be orders of magnitude more worthwhile.

Comment: "I have never used Matlab nor do I have Matlab installed on my computer" It's a completely proprietary product.

Comment: "what the best way to run Matlab code in Java would be. "

Comment: Um? The answer should be given in the paramaters given by the OP.

Comment: @hexafraction So you downvote, and then backoff and delete your post.  Why not let the community decide?  Guess they already did.

Comment: As I've stated I'm not in any mood to argue with you.

Comment: Not in any *position* to argue, or you would have left your post. Hope you have a better day!

Comment: I hope you have a great day as well.